# React Native Redux - How to delete one item at a time

Tags: react-native, redux

I'm creating a react native application for e-commerce purposes and am trying to get the cart functionality working. I'm using redux and I am able to add one item at a time to the cart but when I try to delete an item from the cart, all of the same items get deleted. For example, if I have 2 pencils, 3 pens and 4 notebooks in my cart and I click the delete button on one of the notebooks, all 4 notebooks get removed from my cart. I want to be able to only remove one item at a time.

```js
const cartItems = (state = [], action) => {
   switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TO_CART':
        return [...state, action.payload]
    case 'REMOVE_FROM_CART':
        return state.filter(cartItem => cartItem.id !== action.payload.id)
        //return state.filter(cartItem => cartItem !== action.payload.id
        //const filteredItems = state.filter((cartItem) => cartItem.id !== action.payload.id);
   }

   return state
}

export default cartItems
```

The two lines that are commented out are the other ways I've tried, but ultimately didnt work.

Comment: Firstly, you should not mutate state directly (unless you are using `createReducer`. 
Secondly, you should add your `actions` to the code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```js
return state.filter(cartItem => cartItem.id !== action.payload.id)
```

Means "return a new array consisting of all `state` elements except those which have `id` property matching `action.payload.id`".
So if there are multiple items with the same `id`, all f them will be filtered out.

Since this is just plain JavaScript, you can have any logic here, you just need to return a new array. This, for example, will delete only the first matching element:

```js
let removed = false;
return state.filter(cartItem => {
    if (cartItem.id === action.payload.id && !removed) {
        removed = true;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

A better solution would be to create another identifier for the items in cart, so that the action does not remove the first matching item in the list, but the one the user requested to delete by tapping the delete button.

Comment: I tried implementing it that way but still all the items of the same type get removed.

Comment: @kiran if you mean that you tried adding another ID, it is supposed to be unique for every item in the cart, not for every item in the store.

Comment: I don't think I quite understand what you mean. But the same behavior took place when I tried your code. Like if I had 4 notebooks, and I clicked "remove from cart" on one of the notebooks, all four got removed. How would I create another identifier for the items in the cart? Would that be my product attributes from my backend db?

Comment: @kiran I've corrected the code, you can try again. Should work this time.
My first point was—you can have any logic in your reducer; you are not limited to a specific usage of `Array.filter(…)` method.
My second point was—if there can be multiple items with the same ID in the shopping cart, right now you have no way of distinguishing between 2 items that are the same, say, 2 pencils. In order to point at a specific pencil in the cart, you need both pencils to have some sort of identifiers that are different from each other.

Comment: ya so now it works like you had explained. So my question is how do I go about assigning different ids for the same product? Because my next problem will be refining the delete functionality and also trying to incorporate the products and their quantities as well as price to the overall state of the redux. This is new to me and I'm still trying to learn how redux works.

Comment: @kiran the index of an item in the state array can serve as a "shopping card item ID", for example.

Comment: would I need to incorporate that in the reducer to start calculating total price or to delete the item tapped by the user?